# integrating cvblobslib in opencv

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

here I have just started my fyp and ints gona be in opencv.
I needed to vectorize the image and in order to do that I chose to use cvblobslib.
I downloaded it and it was build successfully but when I use it in my project there's a link error saying that "could not open cvblobslib.obj"
the exact string is pasted below

fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'E:\Faizan\myWork\moCap\blobslib\Debug\cvblobslib.obj'

of the solutions which I found on net and tried on my project are to remove any spaces in path, build in release mode rather than in debug mode, but problem was not solved.
the thing is that the stated file does not get built with other files when cvblobslib is built, i.e it is not there in the stated folder.

any body please give a solution

Comment: FWIW I didn't have much luck with cvblobslib so I ended up writing my own CCL routine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cvBlobsLib` has been developed using `Microsoft Visual C++ (6.0)` and can also be used in `.NET.` A Linux version could be downloaded [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=cvblobslib_v6p1.tar.gz).

`cvBlobsLib` is distributed in a static library (.lib). To use it, it is requred that you build the .lib file and later use that lib file in the desired project. To build the .lib file, simply open the MSVC++ project and build it (debug or release version).

To build the project where the library is to be used follow this steps (MSVC++ 6.0):

In `Project/Settings/C++/Preprocessor/Additional Include directories` add the directory where the blob library is stored
In `Project/Settings/Link/Input/Additional library path` add the directory where the blob library is stored and in `Object/Library modules` add the cvblobslib.lib file
Include the file `BlobResult.h` where you want to use blob variables.
In `Project/Settings/C++/Precompiled Headers` select `Not use precompiled headers`
NOTE: Verify that in the project where the cvblobslib.lib is used, the MFC Runtime Libraries are not mixed:

Check in `Project->Settings->C/C++->Code Generation->Use run-time library` of your project and set it to
*Debug Multithreaded DLL (debug version)* or to *Multithreaded DLL ( release version )*.
Check in "Project->Settings->General" how it uses the MFC. It should be "Use MFC in a shared DLL".
**NOTE:** The library can be compiled and used in .NET using this steps, but the menu options may differ a little

**NOTE 2:** In the .NET version, the character sets must be equal in the .lib and in the project. [OpenCV yahoo group: Msg 35500]

**NOTE 3:** `cvBlobsLib` might give errors when building with OpenCV v2.2 onwards. Try commenting out this line in file `BlobLibraryConfiguration.h`:

```
#define _SHOW_ERRORS
```

**NOTE 4:** If you are using the new `cv::Mat` for your images instead of the old `IplImage`, you can easily convert between them, such as by following the [OpenCV C++ Cheatsheet.](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=opencv_cheatsheet.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to use the cvblobslib for?  I also tried using this with no luck.  I found that openCV has a lot of the same capabilities.  For example, you can use cvCountours to detect "blobs" and filter them by area.

(ps. i tried leaving this as a comment. do you need certain amount of rep to do that?)

Comment: I need it to vectorize edges of an image. after reading a few papers and searching over internet I came to know that it can be very useful and efficient, as my system is going to be real time so, I need some efficient implementation...